# how to upload the file in local public disk of laravel from vue js app?

Tags: javascript, laravel, file, vue.js, asyncfileupload

hi there I want to upload the file into local public  directory of laravel from vue js app and only send the **unique name** to mysql on form submission. but don't know how to do that with js

```
// template tag
<input type="file" @change="uploadFile" >


// methods on Vue Js app


methods: {
uploadFile(){
 // logic to upload the file in local public disk and only send the unique name to mysql 
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should still make an API for that. And upload it trough the api

I have a code here, Maybe it can help. just add it in your laravel controller,.

```
$user = User::find($request->user_id);
        if ($request->file('profile_image') !== null) {
            $imageProfile = $request->file('profile_image');
            $imageProfileSanitizedName = time() . $imageProfile->getClientOriginalName();
            $imageProfile->move("images/", $imageProfileSanitizedName);
            $user->image = $imageProfileSanitizedName;
        }
        $user->save();
```

This function
 `$imageProfile->move("images/", $imageProfileSanitizedName);` will move to the
public/images directory of your laravel project.

i added `time()` function so that the image file will unique.

dont forget to use formData in the axios in your vuejs method.

Comment: thanks for help i got to know that i can move the file only in server side code like you explained